# Java: how to loop indefinitely without crashing the program?

Tags: java, loops

I have a game which is a simple version of Conway's Game of Life.

When I push the "run" button, I want the program to indefinitely loop, playing turns of the game.

I already have the two following methods which play a round of the game(`game.playGameTick();`) and then update the visible board ( `updateVisibleBoard();`).

```
playForeverButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        for (;;) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                //to create a delay
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            game.playGameTick();

            updateVisibleBoard();
        }
    }
});
```

When I press the button, it doesn't do anything. The board is not updated and the game doesn't start.

Comment: Do those methods work when you don't call them in an action listener?

Comment: If the button doesn't do anything, then the problem is with code that we can't see.  The "indefinite loop" has nothing to do with it.  The title of the post is misleading, since it has nothing to do with the real problem, and you've already confused two answerers into focusing on the wrong thing.

Comment: @ajb Zombie processes that run forever playing conways game of life... never ever stopping? I'm not sure we want to see *this* code.

Comment: Elliott: come on, programming game of life and watching gliders move over the canvas hitting other structures... every programmer should do that once in his life. Without damaging his wrist because of one has to click  buttons all the time :-)

Comment: I wrote one: [Primer](https://cgl.herokuapp.com/primer), [Quadratic Growth Pattern](https://cgl.herokuapp.com/breeder1)

Comment: Your problem is that the endless loop blocks the Swing EDT, thereby preventing Swing from ever updating the UI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Try This

What you're looking for is a game loop. Something that runs `true` while the game is still running. Perhaps [this is what you're looking for?](http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=24220.0)

Most engines have a lot of documentation on this stuff. Try poking around at Java game engines, or even JavaScript game engines.

If you're really feeling adventurous, [Unity](https://unity3d.com) has amazing documentation on all of its code and functions. On top of that, if you're looking to build more games in the future OpenGl is the defacto library to build in right now, but Vulkan is making some great headway too.

#### My Thoughts

Game loops are a great way of keeping track of time frames within the game. They allow for multiple loops within them that give you full access to time and physics. When using a game loop try keeping only necessities within it so that it doesn't become hard to read and understand in the future.

### Example

```
public game_loop() {
    update_timer(); // Update the timer because everything else past this point will depend on the time this game loop started running
    physics_update(); // Run calculations and setup events
    update(); // Here would loop through each object
    fixed_update(); // Would loop through each object again, but provide a more concise time frame based on screen updates, frame rate and physics
}
```

Comment: At least put enough information in your answer so that removing the link doesn't make it completely pointless.

Comment: Just trying to help best I can :)

Comment: See [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). And consider the hypothetical question, "If this link were to longer work, would my answer still have any useful information in it, enough to fully answer the question?" Believe me, it happens. Links go dead all the time, I've had to update tons of my answers because of that.

Comment: I've never thought of it that way before @PatrickRoberts. That does help and I'll be sure to post in the future a kind of generalization or brief explanation/example on what I'm talking about